# Binding BitmapImage UriSource with x:Static and static property can't find the Class at build time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.5

I am creating a WPF application with .Net 4.5 and Visual Studio 2013.

I have a BitMapImage that I am binding its UriSource to a Static Property of a class. The property exists, if I do F12 it goes to the definition, both the class and the xaml are in the same Assembly.

If I build the Application with the XAML open I always get:

> The name "MyImagePaths" does not exist in the namespace
>   "clr-namespace:MyNamespace".

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:namespace1="clr-namespace:MyNamespace">
<BitmapImage x:Key="MyImage"  UriSource="{x:Static namespace1:MyImagePaths.MyImage}"/>
```

The Class:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class MyImagePaths
    {
           public static Uri MyImage = new Uri(MyImagePath, UriKind.Relative);
           public const string MyImagePath = "/MyNamespace;component/Images/myImage.png";
```

If close the XAML and build Everything works fine, and the application runs.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way not to get this error when the xaml is open while building?

Comment: It doesn't reproduce. I think path statement in other part might be wrong. You had better post the complete code.

Comment: ***Everything works fine, and the application runs*** - so it is just fine and I see nothing wrong. It's just a buggy feature of XAML editor. I said to many that they simply should not believe in what XAML editor reports to you. Almost the time it reports correctly but sometimes it's just simply wrong, sometimes after rebuilding the project it's correct again.

Comment: @KingKing - I have noticed that the XAML Editor has that tendency, but it is extremely annoying, and makes me wonder if there might be something not quite right or a way to solve the issue.

Comment: @emoacht - I can't post the actual code, but it is about the same than this. I was really careful when changing the names, etc..

Comment: I have a project in which a large chunk of XAML code is underlined for no reason however it just builds and runs fine. I consider it's a bug and simply ignore what XAML editor says. I don't think you have any way to avoid that. It's still better than Notepad. In fact if you understand XAML well, you don't need to care much what it says - simply think of yourself that you're better than it.

Comment: @Dzyann I mean minimal reproducible code, not necessarily actual code of you app.

Comment: `{x:Static ...}` is not a binding. How about `UriSource="{Binding Path=(namespace1:MyImagePaths.MyImage)}"`?

Comment: @emoacht - That is the code related to the issue, there are several other BitImage in the same file, but they are working fine. I think the issue is probably like KingKing said :(

Comment: @Clemens - I was hoping no-one would pick on my loose use the word binding (just didn't know a better word to use). I tried your suggestion, but I get the same error :(